# How to resume files copying from broken hard drive?

Tags: windows, copy-paste

I have an external hard drive that randomly crash. In windows it looks like it was physically disconnected and reconnected.
I want to copy one big file (+200go) from it.
Standard copying is not a solution since the hard drive always crash.
Is there a way to resume the copy where the crash happened ?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest using specialized data recovery tools to copy/image the entire disk. I often use `ddrescue` for CDs/DVDs. However, this is Linux software and a disk image requires lots of space.

Comment: You continue damaging the drive by repeatadly trying. There are tools that also support retrying a copy. I do think xcopy/robocopy might be able or e.g. Total Commander (or one of the alternatives) might feature that as well. As you might be copying garbage anyway it's hard to tell how worth it this is going to be.

Answer (score 1):

> Standard copying is not a solution since the hard drive always crash.
> Is there a way to resume the copy where the crash happened ?

If the disk is damaged in the area of the large file, then the file may not be recoverable.

There are utilities that can recover files but they may not work for the damaged file.

Before using these utilities, consider getting an assessment for data recovery from a local disk recovery agency.

Recuva:   [CC Cleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva)

Easus:  [Data Recovery](https://www.easeus.com/ad/data-recovery-software.html?gclid=Cj0KCQiAuP-OBhDqARIsAD4XHpdjoooSYa0NcFUbCdWKT5EYDaLw2U0jXmzXKlTXk98mRC46CVKpmugaAkIWEALw_wcB)

Spinrite:  [Gibson Research](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm)

.

Again, if the file is very important to you, you may first wish to take your drive to a local disk recovery agency for an estimate. Greater damage costs more money.

You can use the software I pointed to if the file is not truly of great importance.

Comment: Using professional services is your best hope. They will in the correct environment determine the reason the drive crashes, resolve the problem, and use specialized software to recover the data. Commercialized data recovery software is entirely different than the stuff you find on the internet